# shiny: apply shinycustomerloader after pressing actionButton

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

#### BACKGROUND

I have an app where a user chooses a file name from a drop-down menu (`selectizeInput`) and confirms the choice with an `actionButton`. The app will display the results in the `DT::dataTableOutput` format.

#### OBJECTIVE

I'd like to be able to show a loading screen (using `shinydashboardloader` package) but only AFTER a user presses the `actionButton`. Prior that I'd like to show an empty screen. Additionally, if a user wants to try several files in one session, the loading screen should appear every time the `actionButton` has been pressed and disappear when the dataset has been loaded.

#### CURRENT STATE

Currently, if I run this app the loading button appears all the time, also before a user makes a file choice

```
### ui.R
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)
library(shinycustomloader)

dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(

selectizeInput("file", "Select File",
               c("fileA", "fileB")), 

actionButton("submit", "Submit")
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      box(h2("My Data"),
      div(style = 'overflow-x: scroll', 
          withLoader(DT::dataTableOutput('mytable'),
                     type = "html",
                     loader = "loader1")),
      width = 12)

  )
  )
)


#### server.R
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)


shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {  

  file_name <- reactive({ 
req(input$file)
  })


  # When the Submit button is clicked, start the cleaning and matching 
  observeEvent(input$submit, {

## open chosen file 
#    open_file <- read_excel(paste0("input_files/", file_name()))

### + some processing that gives me matched_df

matched_df <- data.frame(A = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
                         B = c("A", "B", "C", "D"))

selected <- reactive({

  matched_df # + apply some filter

}) 



output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({
  selected()
})


  })

})
```

I'm guessing that the way forward would be to use `conditionalPanel` but I'm not sure how to make a click on the `actionButton` a condition.

### UPDATE

I applied `conditionalPanel` to the datatable, but it works only the first time I press "Submit" button. If in the same session I change the file name and press the button again, the loader won't appear. Any ideas how I can make it work multiple times in one session?

```
  dashboardBody(
     fluidRow(
      box(h2("My Data"),
          conditionalPanel("input.submit==1",
          div(style = 'overflow-x: scroll', 
              withLoader(DT::dataTableOutput('mytable'),
                     type = "html",
                     loader = "loader1"))
      ),
      width = 12)
```

Any help will be great, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1:  I'm not familiar with `shinydashboardloader` but I was able add a loading indicator to my app by using the `shinyjs` package to hide and show elements using CSS. I would add your loading page elements to your main page and wrap them in a `shinyjs::hidden` function so they're hidden by default. Then when the user clicks the action button, call `shinyjs::showElement` to show them and `shinyjs::hideElement` to hide them once loading is complete.

UI:

```
shinyjs::hidden(div(id = 'loading',
           # PUT LOADING ELEMENTS HERE))
```

SERVER:

```
observeEvent(input$submit, {
    # Show element once submit button is pressed
    shinyjs::showElement(id = 'loading')

    # CODE TO MAKE DATA FRAME

    # Hide loading element when done
    shinyjs::hideElement(id = 'loading')
)
```

2:  As for your problem with your edit, the reason that your conditional panel only shows the first time is that the value of an `actionButton` increases by one each time it is clicked. So the first time it is clicked it goes from 0 to 1; if you click it again it goes from 1 to 2 and so on. Since you set the condition to `input$select == 1`, it will only appear if the button has been clicked exactly 1 time.

To get it to do what you want, you either need to change the condition to `input$select > 1` so that it appears as long as the button has been clicked once, or add a `reactiveValue` that gets set to 1 when the button is clicked and then resets to 0 when another condition is met (like when loading finishes).

```
rv <- reactiveValues(loading = 0)

# When you click submit, show the loading screen
observeEvent(input$submit, {rv$loading <- 1})

# When you click LOAD, start loading, then hide the loading screen when finished
observeEvent(input$LOAD, {

    # CODE TO LOAD AND GENERATE DATA HERE

    rv$loading <- 0})
```

Comment: thanks for really useful tips! They all make sense, but...! 1) I'm not sure how to isolate a loading page as an independent element, as `shinycustomloader` can be only applied to the actual output.

Comment: The problems I have with point 2 is that if I set  `input.submit>=1` then the loading page doesn't appear when I load a second, third, etc dataset, probably because there's already previous output in the `dashboardBody`. How could I define 'loading finishes' state programatically, if I wanted to use it for `reactiveValue` conditioning?

Comment: thanks for editing your answer. I'm still getting there but the first solution you proposed seems most likely to work - I'll need to dig out the CSS code from `shinydashboardloader` and take it from there. Thanks!

Comment: one more question re the above: if I have a css script for the loading screen, where and how do I include it in `shinyjs::hidden(div(id = 'loading',
           # PUT LOADING ELEMENTS HERE))`? I assumed it goes in `dasboardBody` (not nested in `fluidRow`) and then tried to wrap it in `includeCSS()`, but had 0 success.

Comment: I would keep all the CSS together and use selectors that target the `id` for the loading screen, rather than having multiple linked style sheets. If you're trouble with `includeCSS`, I had better luck manually linking it: `tags$head(tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "styles.css"))`